# How to get only one record from another table using Join

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, left-join

I have a table for hotel.Also i have a table for the hotel Image.For a particular hotel there will multiple images in the hotel image table.

I need to get only single image of the all  the hotels .while using left join i am gettting all the images of particular hotel.I need only one image of all the hotel.

Hotel Table

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_hotel` (
  `int_hotel_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `str_country_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `str_hotel_name` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `int_property_type_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `int_hotel_theme_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `str_hotel_facility` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `str_star_category` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `str_web_url` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `str_hotel_mail_id` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `txt_hotel_description` text,
  `str_hotel_city_name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `str_hotel_address` text NOT NULL,
  `str_hotel_address2` text NOT NULL,
  `int_hotel_zip_code` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `str_hotel_phone` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `str_hotel_fax_no` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `bit_allow_booking` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  `bit_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `str_account_type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`int_hotel_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=95 ;
```

Hotel image

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_hotel_image` (
  `int_image_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `str_image_name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `txt_image_description` text,
  `int_hotel_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `bit_main_image` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  `bit_active` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`int_image_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=119 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The join binds both tables, but the [GROUP BY] acts like a record compression, getting the records with the same value, in this case, its getting only one record from **tbl_hotel_imgage.int_hotel_id** [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-optimization.html) you can find more information of this statement.

```
    Select * from 
         tbl_hotel inner join tbl_hotel_image on 
         tbl_hotel_image.int_hotel_id=tbl_hotel.int_hotel_id
    Group by
        tbl_hotel_image.int_hotel_id;
```

Comment: This would only retrieve one hotel, not one image per hotel.

Comment: You mean you want 1 image per hotel then?

Comment: That's what it says in the question.

Comment: He edited the question with the correct question, btw, 1 sec, i will do the propper changes...

Comment: YEAH  i mean 1 image per hotel

Comment: i need to get hotel information  such as name ,desc etc from tbl_hotel along with 1 image of the hotel from tbl_hotel_image

Comment: Check it as answered please :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select * from tbl_hotel h 
  join (select 
               int_image_id, 
               str_image_name,       
               @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
        from tbl_hotel_image,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  image_id) img
    on h.int_hotel_id = img.int_hotel_id
) q 
where rank = 1
```